# Ordering users by custom user meta

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of users, and I would like to select a few to appear at the beginning of the "faculty" page, and then display the rest afterward in alphabetical order.

With the following code (modified from the github link, below), I have added a faculty_order field as user meta data to each user.

https://gist.github.com/magnific0/29c32c7dabc89ab9cae5

```
function mysite_custom_define() {
  $custom_meta_fields = array();
  $custom_meta_fields['faculty_position'] = 'Faculty Order';
  return $custom_meta_fields;
}

function mysite_columns($defaults) {
  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    $defaults[('mysite-usercolumn-' . $meta_number . '')] = __($meta_disp_name, 'user-column');
  }
  return $defaults;
}

function mysite_custom_columns($value, $column_name, $id) {
  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    if( $column_name == ('mysite-usercolumn-' . $meta_number . '') ) {
      return get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $id );
    }
  }
}

function mysite_show_extra_profile_fields($user) {
  print('<h3>Extra profile information</h3>');

  print('<table class="form-table">');

  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    print('<tr>');
    print('<th><label for="' . $meta_field_name . '">' . $meta_disp_name . '</label></th>');
    print('<td>');
    print('<input type="text" name="' . $meta_field_name . '" id="' . $meta_field_name . '" value="' . esc_attr( get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $user->ID ) ) . '" class="regular-text" /><br />');
    print('<span class="description"></span>');
    print('</td>');
    print('</tr>');
  }
  print('</table>');
}

function mysite_save_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {

  if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
    return false;

  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_field_name, $_POST[$meta_field_name] );
  }
}

add_action('show_user_profile', 'mysite_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'mysite_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('personal_options_update', 'mysite_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'mysite_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'mysite_custom_columns', 15, 3);
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'mysite_columns', 15, 1);
```

And then on the faculty page I have this query :

```
                    $get_user_args = array(
                        'blog_id'     => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
                        'role'        => $bioRole,
                        //'orderby'   => 'faculty_order',
                        'meta_key' => 'faculty_order',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'DESC'

                        'meta_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'key' => 'faculty_order', 
                                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'faculty_order', 
                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                            )
                                //,
                        ),


                        'count_total' => false,
                        'include'      => $user_string
                    );
```

This query shows all the faculty members, but those members with user meta (1, 2, 3, etc...) don't show up first.

Any advice much appreciated. Thank you.